# Enable CORS in Java without spring (Just vanilla Java)

Tags: java, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to learn how to build an HTTP server with Java alone before I get to Springboot. As I was working on this REST API, I tried to make a request via Next.js. There are no errors, but I cannot get the data for some reason. I am guessing its the CORS policy on the Java server.

SO I would like to know how to enable CORS in the main file if possible.

MAIN FILE:: Sets up the server with a thread poool of 10 and calls MyHTTPHandler

```
package org.example;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080), 0);
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        server.createContext("/test", new MyHttpHandler());
        server.setExecutor(threadPoolExecutor);
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server started on port 8080");
    }
}
```

HTTP HANDLER:: A simple GET request for the browser to send the message "HEELLO"

```
package org.example;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MyHttpHandler implements HttpHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("REQUEST_METHOD::" + httpExchange.getRequestMethod());

        OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
        String str = "HEELLO";
        if(httpExchange.getRequestMethod().equals("GET")){
            httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, str.length());
            outputStream.write(str.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

NEXT.JS FETCH FUNCTION:: Gets the data from the Java Rest API and displays it in the console

```
async function gett() {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/test`)

    return res
  }

export default async function Page() {

    const getData = gett()

    const [data1] = await Promise.all([getData])

    console.log(data1)

    return <h1>DASHBOARD/settings</h1>
  }
```

This Code doesn't seem to throw any errors but I feel like I am missing something with the NEXT.js code that I cant find on Google. Essentially, the fetch does not seem to work. I believe its becuase of Java's CORS policy, but I am not sure how Java is set by default and there is no notification, or error message about it.

Thanks in advance